# java packages and interfaces

Tags: java, interface, package

I am Practicing packages. i have three files in a directory name animals. these files states.

```
/*filename Eat.java*/
package animal;
public interface Eat{

public void food();

}
```

2nd file:

```
    /*Animal.java*/
    package animal;
    public interface Animal{

    public void move();

}
```

3rd file which implements the above interface

```
/*Dog.java*/
package animal;
public class Dog implements Animal,Eat
{
int movesteps=2;
String food="MEAT";
Dog()
{

move();
food();


}
public void move()
{
System.out.println("I am a dog i can move just "+this.movesteps+" steps/sec");

}
public void food()
{
System.out.println("I am a dog i only eat "+this.food);

}
public static void main(String args[])
{

Dog myDoggy=new Dog();

System.exit(0);

}
```

The problem is that when i compile the Dog.class without packages in all the classes it runs fine but when i include them in package the compiler comes with a lot of errors in notepad++.

Comment: What's the error, can you post it?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError:Eat(wrong name:animal/Eat).....atJava.lang.ClassLoader.DefineClass1(Native Method)...atJava.lang.ClassLoader.DefineClass(Unkown source)......atJava.security.secureClassLoader.DefineClass1(Unknown Source)..etc

Comment: 'without packages in all the classes' what does it mean ? Only Dog class not compile or all ?

Comment: means if I exclude the package details from all of the files . ass all other are interfaces i only compile Dog but it comes up with errors without package definition its working fine

Comment: kk mean when u add package u r facing issue & if remove package from all the files its working.Can u provide the cmd d directory structure ?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the directory tree from the ide?

Comment: commands:cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
javac $(FILE_NAME)
java $(NAME_PART)

Comment: directory path : D:\javapractice\interface\animals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer after a long search and testing the particular code on other IDE's. The issue is with the Notepadd++. It runs fine on all other IDE's thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

All java files should be in "animal" directory:

```
- animal
|- Eat.java
|- Animal.java
|- Dog.java
```

If you have all classes in a package like "com.some.package" the path should be

```
- com
|- some
 |-package
  |- Eat.java
  |- Animal.java
  |- Dog.java
```

Comment: They need to have the same package names: `package animal`, and they need to be compiled as such. Where the Java source-code files are does not matter. As long as the class files are accessible by the JVM.

Comment: I think i have mentioned above that all the files are in animal directory :-)

Comment: Well, it doesn't make *sense* to put the java code into different directories, but as far as the OP's problem, the source code *could* be in different directories without encountering a `NoClassDefFound`.

Comment: What does "without packages in all the classes" mean? Your directory structure is the same i wrote?

Comment: means if I exclude the package details from all of the files . ass all other are interfaces i only compile Dog but it comes up with errors without package definition its working fine

Comment: Please, post a screenshot of your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory `D:\javapractice\interface` and open the cmd.Keep all the three java files under directory `D:\javapractice\interface\animals`.

```
D:\javapractice\interface
- animal
|- Eat.java
|- Animal.java
|- Dog.java
```

Now start compiling the java classes

Cmd :    `D:\javapractice\interface>`

```
javac animal\Eat.java
javac animal\Animal.java
javac animal\Dog.java
```

You will find three .class at the location D:\javapractice\interface\animal

Now time to run it :

```
java animal.Dog
```

Comment: @user2641848 can u try it .

Comment: Niks bro do you have team viewer or skype?

Comment: just give me some time.I m installing team viewer

Comment: yeah please if you kindly give me your ID and I will show you this at my my end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48156/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-user2641848)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create separate source and output directories where your classes will be compiled to. Unless you specify an output directory, your classes will be compiled into your source directories. That's a real recipe for pain when you need to delete your old class files (and you'll need to eventually).

Supposing you have this directory structure:

```
.
├── classes
└── src
    └── animal
        ├── Animal.java
        ├── Dog.java
        └── Eat.java
```

Compile like this:

```
javac -d classes -sourcepath src src/animal/Dog.java
```

You'll end up with:

```
.
├── classes
│   └── animal
│       ├── Animal.class
│       ├── Dog.class
│       └── Eat.class
└── src
    └── animal
        ├── Animal.java
        ├── Dog.java
        └── Eat.java
```

One tip: If you compile the most dependent class (i.e. Dog.java), javac will compile its dependencies (Animal, Eat). That way you don't have to execute javac 3 times.